# How do I Retrieve the choice values of a column in a Document Library

Tags: web-part, document-library, visual-studio, sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part

I am fairly new to SharePoint development and as you may all know that it is very basic for one to know how to access fields in a choice column...

My problem: 
I want to access the values of the Check Boxes from a Choice Column.

For Example: 
I have a document library called Libe, this document library has a custom column with type Choice and has 4 checkboxes with the values:

1. Category 1
2. Category 2
3. Category 3
4. Category 4

How do I get the values like literally the text values of what is in the Check Box List: "Category 1", "Category 2" ... "Category 4".

Any ideas?

I can access the column fine and get the selected values, I just do not know how to get the values the user can choose from.

Your help is very appreciated.

### -------------------------------------

ANSWER:

```
 SPFieldMultiChoice Fld = (SPFieldMultiChoice)list.Fields["Column"];
                                List<string> fieldList = new List<string>();
                                foreach (string str in Fld.Choices)
                                {
                                    fieldList.Add(str);


     }
```

Above is the answer, I can't answer my own question until I have a 100 rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice columns are worked with SPFieldMultiChoice and SPFieldMultiChoiceValue classes. Here are a few posts with examples -

[How to retrieve and update from a multi choice Checkboxlist field](http://alectang.com/blog/archive/2010/03/15/how-to-retrieve-and-update-from-a-multi-choice-checkboxlist-field.aspx)

[Properly Populating and Retrieving SharePoint Field Data](http://sharepointcodeblock.blogspot.com/2008/07/properly-populating-and-retrieving.html)